# Find parent element of a token in CodeMirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I've posted the same question on Google Groups, bu to no avail. I'll sync the answer if found here.

*Side note: reminded me again why I despise Google Groups. The format and the usability are just awful.*

Anyway...

Imagine that I have the following HTML in CodeMirror in XML mode:

```
<div data-id="parent"><span data-id="test"></span></div>
```

I am able, on right-click or hover (or any other user-initiated event, really), to get the token the mouse is over. It's name and type.

**My question - can I get "parent" token and its attributes?**

To illustrate:

1. if I clicked on `test`, I'd like to be able to tell that it's value of attribute `data-id` "under" `span`.
2. if I clicked on `span`, I'd like to be able to get its `data-id`, but also to know that it's "under" `div` token.

This, of course, assumes that the language provides concept of "parent" or "under"... which I guess XML/HTML does.

**Any ideas?** Is there an API for that, either in CM or XML/HTML corresponding mode?

I've tried going the parsing route - getting stuff around the "current" token, but it's very ugly and doesn't properly work.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no API for that. A while ago, I tried to write a code around the "token" to get to the parent element, the code was ugly and slow in some cases, so I limited code to return current element and its attributes.

Answer (score 5):

```
var cur = cm.getCursor()
var token = cm.getTokenAt(cur);
var inner = CodeMirror.innerMode(cm.getMode(), token.state);
var cx = inner.state.context
var tagName = cx.tagName
```